# Angular directive does not work if we change name

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am seeing a strange behaviour when using angular directive.

In the code below

HTML

```
<body ng-app="loadTweetsModule">
    <div tweets> Load </div>
    <div loadTweets> loadTweets </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var loadTweetsModule = angular.module("loadTweetsModule",[]);


loadTweetsModule.directive('tweets',function(){
    return {
        link : function(scope,element){
            element.bind("mouseenter", function(){
                console.log("tweets");
            });
        }
    };
});

loadTweetsModule.directive('loadTweets',function(){
    return {
        link : function(scope,element){
            element.bind("mouseenter", function(){
                console.log("loadTweets");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/manojpcw/XWEq6/)

The two directive `loadTweets` and `tweets` are the same except for the name. The directive `tweets` works as expected but `loadTweets` does not work. I am not able to find out the reason for this behaviour. Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you write in js `loadTweets` you should write in html `load-tweets`

from http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> Directives have camel cased names such as ngBind. The directive can be
>   invoked by translating the camel case name into snake case with these
>   special characters :, -, or _. Optionally the directive can be
>   prefixed with x-, or data- to make it HTML validator compliant. Here
>   is a list of some of the possible directive names: ng:bind, ng-bind,
>   ng_bind, x-ng-bind and data-ng-bind.

Comment: Now I remember reading about it and it simply did not strike me even though we do that for other directive. Thanks!